# the azure access control service is unavailable

Tags: azure

I have a high trust provider-hosted app on **sharepoint on-premise**, with web app hosted on **Azure** , and while accessing the app I see the "**the azure access control service is unavailable**" error in fiddler. I have created an S2S certificate and added a SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer on the sharepoint farm. 
Has anyone faced this before?

Please Advice.